# alerts/notification set up for file upload from local into Google storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a script that uploads CSV data files from a local drive into the google cloud storage bucket.
the script is scheduled to run every 15 minutes and any new files will be uploaded into the bucket.

I am wondering if we can set up notifications/alerts to tell us when no data has been uploaded within the last 24 hours.

Sensors data save as CSV in the Local drive and the script sends them to the bucket. I want to get an alert when sensors stop working and no data file is uploaded into the bucket within the past 24 hours.

(Sensors do not generate data regularly, few files per day, but if they don't generate any within 24 hours there should be something wrong and needs an alert)

Extra: The second phase of alerting system would be getting alerts for a specific sensor when it is not generating data. Currently, we have 4-5 sensors and the data files are named "sensorName_timestamp.csv"
I would like to get an alert if each sensor is not generating data within the past 24 hours.

Comment: Do you think a cloud function can be developed to check what is going on in a bucket, and raise an alert (for example, or do whatever you would like) if the 'youngest' object in a bucket is 'older' than 24 hours? And such function may be triggered to run regularly (every 'few' minutes, for example).

Comment: Thanks @al-dann. What is function's trigger then?

Comment: Currently I have a cloud functions which gets triggered with any new data upload into the bucket. As soon as a new csv file is uploaded into the bucket, cloud function will upload data into bigquery but the trigger for this finction is new upload into the storage bucket. I am not sure how we can trigger a function if there is no upload?!

Comment: I think a cloud scheduler https://cloud.google.com/scheduler can be used for triggering cloud functions on a regular basis.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @al-dann, You can use a [cloud scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler) for triggering cloud functions to set an alert or notifications.

> With Cloud Scheduler you set up scheduled units of work to be executed at defined times or regular intervals. These work units are commonly known as cron jobs. Typical use cases might include sending out a report email on a daily basis, updating cached data every 10 minutes, or updating summary information once an hour.

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/schedule-run-cron-job